# How can I set a var in a function, and have it persist outside said function?

Tags: javascript

I want to set a variable based on a click, and then increment that same variable based on another click.

```
$("#set-1").click(function() {
  var x = 1;
});
$("#set-2").click(function() {
  var x = 2;
});
$("#set-3").click(function() {
  var x = 3;
});
//...
$("#increment").click(function() {
  x = x + 1;
});
```

But when I click on `#increment`, `x` is no longer defined. How can I get it to stay defined, even outside of the function it is defined in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare it outside:

```js
var x;
$("#set-1").click(function() {
  x = 1;
});
$("#set-2").click(function() {
  x = 2;
});
$("#set-3").click(function() {
  x = 3;
});
$("#increment").click(function() {
  ++x;
});
```

```js
var x;
$("#set-1").click(function() {
  x = 1;
});
$("#set-2").click(function() {
  x = 2;
});
$("#set-3").click(function() {
  x = 3;
});
$("#increment").click(function() {
  ++x;
});
$('body').click(function() {
  $('#x').text(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="set-1">Set x=1</button>
<button id="set-2">Set x=2</button>
<button id="set-3">Set x=3</button>
<button id="increment">Increment x</button>
<p>x = <span id="x">undefined</span></p>
```

And consider unifying the event handlers:

```js
$('[id ^= "set-"').click(function() {
  x = +this.id.substr(4);
});
```

```js
var x;
$('[id ^= "set-"').click(function() {
  x = +this.id.substr(4);
});
$("#increment").click(function() {
  ++x;
});
$('body').click(function() {
  $('#x').text(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="set-1">Set x=1</button>
<button id="set-2">Set x=2</button>
<button id="set-3">Set x=3</button>
<button id="increment">Increment x</button>
<p>x = <span id="x">undefined</span></p>
```

Comment: But then when I click on #increment, x is set to 1, no matter what #set-x div I clicked beforehand.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eqfrrfsf/1/

Comment: @JoeMorano Only declare `x` outside, not outside and inside. Otherwise the local `x` will be different than the outer one.

Comment: But I need to set x based on the first div I click on. If I declare it outside, won't that just set it to one static value?

Comment: @JoeMorano You can just use `var x;`. Then its value will be `undefined`. But then if you click "Increment" before setting any value, `undefined+1` will produce `NaN`.

Comment: But how can I set the value of `x` based on the first div I click on? I want to set the value of `x` by clicking on `#set-[some value]`, and then increment that value.

Comment: @JoeMorano When you declare a variable, it must have some value (`undefined` by default). You can't know which will be the first clicked button.

Comment: @Oriol 0 seems to be a good initial value `var x = 0;`

Comment: @t3dodson I thought so too, but JoeMorano seems to disagree. So I removed it in my last edit.

Comment: Okay, with that code `x` starts out as 0, and then I set it to, let's say, 5, by clicking on `#set-5`. Then, when I click on `#increment`, I want it to change to 6. But it changes to 1 instead, because it's set back to 0 as soon as the `$("#set-5").click` function is completed.

Comment: @JoeMorano Can't reproduce. Try my code snippets.

Comment: Here's a fiddle:  
www.jsfiddle.net/eqfrrfsf/1 (I don't know why it's not a link)

Comment: @JoeMorano Again: only declare `x` outside, not outside and inside. Otherwise the local `x` will be different than the outer one.